# Multiple choice search in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search, forms, filter

does any one know how to createa search panel similar to the "quick find" bar on this site?

http://www.thebedandbreakfastclub.co.uk

I've been trying to find a plugin or tutorial but have had no luck at all. I'm looking for some thing that filters child categories according the the parent category the user has clicked on.

Please could some one point me in the right direction.

Thanks very much

Danny

Answer (score 0):

Look at the page source; that's not a Wordpress site, though you can see some of the Javascript involved with the search bar. Have you searched for plugins? [WordPress › WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=search&sort=) or asked in the WordPRess forums? There are ways to implement a search like that in WordPress.

Comment: I thanks for the reply. I realise that isn't a wordpress site and have searched for hours to find some thing similar for Wordpress.

I'll give the WP forums ago now. Thought I'd try here first as the WP forums are pretty slow to respond.

What would you call this type of search function? Is there a universal name for it I can limit my searches to?

Comment: Those kinds of mutliple searches can work several different ways, via categories or custom fields. Depends on how you want it to work. I think you'll need to go through different plugins to figure out what you want to do.